# Django 1.11.3 unable to create table in postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql

i am trying to create table in postgresql by django(version 1.11.3). i entered to following information in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'postgres',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'postgres',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'password',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '5432',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

but it is always creating SqLite database. Can anyone answer me please??

i will try to put my settings.py

> Randon strings to add my settings.py :sdfgshrtys yesy ey tyktsyseyk tytyskt ytr ykrtykeyt
>   ykrtytkyrtyktryetyktyewkyweyekyetywekyeyktywek

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'db',                         # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'postgres',                         # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'password',                     # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost',                        # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '5432',                             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = ''

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (

)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

SECRET_KEY = ''

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ex2_postgreSQL.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (

)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Django won't create PostgreSQL database for you... You have to create a database yourself and provide the credentials to settings and Django will create tables and manipulate them.

Comment: Also, it should be `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` if you are using ubuntu

Comment: use `createdb db_name` as mentioned by @zaidfazil before trying migrations

Comment: "postgres" is the default user and default database. its already there but it is not creating tables in there

Comment: @zaidfazil alreay tried

Comment: Any error messages, during `migrate`?

Comment: @zaidfazil you can use `'django.db.backends.postgresql'` in [Django 1.9+](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.9/#database-backends). Much easier to remember!

Comment: even i delete the whole database segment. It is creating SqLite and doesn't show error

Comment: If it's still creating a SQLite database it sounds like it's probably overriding the `DATABASES` dict somewhere else in your `settings.py`. Did you remove the old dict?

Comment: @zaidfazil no error message

Comment: @zaidfazil i can't find any other code segment named "DATABASES"

Comment: To cover all the bases, including the obvious, did you save the settings file after changing `DATABASES`? As Cory Madden said, if it's creating an SQLite database that must come from somewhere. The default for `DATABASES` is an empty dictionary.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida i am using pycharm it automatically saves the file. But will check again

Comment: @PauloAlmeida yes i did it also

Comment: @srk Ok, then are you sure you are using the right settings.py file? What if you comment out the whole `DATABASES` setting? By the way, what is the name of the SQLite database file that is being created? And are you deleting it afterwards to know if it really is being created each time? If you search for its file name in all the code, does it show up somewhere?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida yes i am using right settings.py

Comment: @PauloAlmeida also database created in the my project directory. I delete it each time. And run the code again. But the same result

Comment: And did you try commenting out the `DATABASES` setting? Also, try the original `DATABASES` setting with sqlite but with a different database name, to see if a file with that name is created.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida tried that too

Comment: @PauloAlmeida in every case SqLite database created

Comment: @srk Ok, but was it created with the same name or the new name you put in the settings? By the way, if you comment out `DATABASES` altogether, you should get an error when you go to the shell and try to access the DB (say, run a query). Like I said above, the default `DATABASES` is an empty dictionary and it must be coming from somewhere. If you are using the right settings and there are no other `DATABASES` being set, I don't know where else it could come from.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida my fault it was wrong settings.py

Comment: @srk Ok, good that it was solved. Paraphrasing Sherlock Holmes, "once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth." :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the default PostgreSQL database, but instead create a new one.  Log into your database via the command line than execute >>>CREATE DATABASE yourName

Than update your **settings.py** to use that new database.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
        name: 'yourName'
    }
}
```

Now that you've done that setup the initial tables by going to your websites root directory and typing...

```
>>> python manage.py makemigrations
>>> python manage.py migrate
```

Now the tables should be showing up in your new database.